# Mysql statement splitting part of a variable

Tags: php, mysql

there are basically a lot input fields created with this line

```
$strStatus = generateSelect("s".$row['id'], $statusArray, $row['status']);
```

first parm is the id, so the first created input field looks like : s1, second : s2, ...

other two are not rly important for this question

sql statement:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $sql = "UPDATE form SET status='$value' WHERE id = 's".$key."'";}
```

so i dont rly know how to correctly write the sql statement for a splited variable, but as you could see above that was my try

```
id = 's".$key."'"
```

$key is basically just the id without s

Comment: Er........ What? Is there a question hidden in here somewhere?

Comment: how to correctly write a sql statement with a splitted variable, so if the variable looks like $s51,$s52,$s53, and i have a $key array which includes the id (so 51,52,53), i want to write a sql statement which puts a s in front of the $key.

Comment: If you're creating the input fields with an "s" in the name, that "s" will be in `$_POST`.

Comment: You might look at the VALUES option of INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY

Answer (score 0):

Remember $variables are automatically expanded in a double quoted string. So if all you want to do is to add a 's' in front of a number held in the `$key` variable, this will do that

```
$sql = "UPDATE form SET status='$value' WHERE id = 's$key'";
```